# Regex in php preg_match function

Tags: php, regex, digits

I have a regex pattern

```
<?php 
if(preg_match("/shop[0-9]/", '/shop43')){
    echo "YES";
}
else
{
    echo "NO";
}
 ?>
```

It is working, but 
when i write

```
if(preg_match("/shop[0-9]/", '/shop43d')){
    echo "YES";
}
```

it is working too.The problem is that i need to have ony digits after word "shop",for example
shop1,shop2,...,shop123
What I need to change in my pattern?)
I would be very thankful if somebody could give me a link with some examples of my problem in regex.Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern instead:

```
/^\/shop[0-9]+$/
```

You can simply use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`:

```
/^\/shop\d+$/
```

*Explanation*:

- As `/` used for indicating start/end of expression you have to escape it(to not indicate the end of the expression) -> `\/`.
- `^` anchor matches at the start of the string the regex pattern is applied to.
- `$` anchor matches at the end of the string the regex pattern is applied to.
- `+` repeats the previous item once or more.

<sub>See more info about reg-exps [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).</sub>

Comment: +1, do exactly what you've done but you was faster than me :)